# External packages implementing custom declared interface in Golang

Tags: go, types, interface

I'm creating a single function to marshal various go-client resources: `*v1.Namespace`, `*v1.Pod`, etc.
Idea was to make them implement a custom interface and create a function where the argument's type would be interface I declared:

```
package kubernetes

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
)

type Marshalable interface {
    Marshal()
}

func (obj *v1.Namespace) Marshal() {

}

func (obj *v1.Pod) Marshal() {
}

func marshal(obj Marshalable) string {
    y, err := yaml.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(y)
}
```

`Marshal()` is just an empty function in order for types to be able to implement the interface. But of course, as go-client resources come from an external package, I cannot do that. Any advice?

Comment: What kind of marshalling are you doing here? JSON? Binary?

Comment: I'm doing JSON marshalling.

Comment: I could not make sense as to why you took the problem upside down. Marshal takes in *any* type and produce *bytes/strings*. There is no need for the types to be marshaled to implement a marshal function unless some corner cases that should remain as episodic as possible.

Comment: The idea is to call `marshal(obj Marshalable)` function from other places where Kubernetes objects are retrieved. I want just to have a single `marshal(obj Marshable)` function with error handling, etc., and that it could be called from multiple places. Method `Marshal()` is just an empty method in order to implement `Marshable` interface. Maybe the method's name is confusing, with `yaml.Marshal(obj)`, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a type definition local to your package:

```
type Namespace v1.Namespace
type Pod v1.Pod
```

and define methods on these local types:

```
func (obj *Namespace) Marshal() {}
func (obj *Pod) Marshal()       {}
```

and to use:

```
var ns  *v1.Namespace
var pod *v1.Pod

(*Namespace)(ns).Marshal()
(*Pod)(pod).Marshal()
```

then your generic `Marshal` function could look something like this:

```
// added error return - as this is standard practice with a marshaler
func Marshal(obj interface{}) ([]byte, error) {

    if v, ok := obj.(*v1.Namespace); ok {
        return (*Namespace)(v).Marshal()
    }

    if v, ok := obj.(*v1.Pod); ok {
        return (*Pod)(v).Marshal()
    }

    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unsupported type: %T", obj)
}
```

or move your type marshaling logic directly into the above function.

https://play.golang.org/p/vwL-CrtGBRR